# Organize values like a matrix in csv datafile

Tags: arrays, vbscript, formatting, string-formatting

Actually I am writing a file converter tool. The data values represent a 120x120 matrix. My first thought was two nested for loops and just a new line inside the first: Easy.

The input file has a vbNewLine each fith value.
I parsed the input file into a string `strAll`.

**Input**

strAll contains 10 character long values

```
"  -24.1189"  (two blanks before value)
"    1.2345"  (four blanks before value)
```

**Output**

```
-24.1189;-24.1189; (...total 120 values...)
-24.1234;-24.1189; (...total 120 values...)
(... total 120 rows ...)
```

Using `Mid` hat should be easy to parse: `Mid(strAll, 1+i, 10+i)`, where `i` is the counter in a for loop. A `Replace(stAll, "  ", "")` should remove all the 3 blanks, 2 blanks and one blank.

**Question:** How to output the string to a file, formatted like a matrix?

```
Dim intValueLength, maxValue, intValueInRowMax
intValueLength=10
intValueInRowMax=120
maxValues=intValueInRowMax * intValueInRowMax



Sub Strg2Array
  arrAll = array()

  ' convert to array
      For i=1 To maxValues
        ReDim Preserve arrAll(UBound(arrAll) +1)
        arrAll(UBound(arrAll)) = Mid(strAll, 1+(i-1)*intValueLength, i*intValueLength)
      Next
End Sub

Sub SaveAll
      Dim intValueInRow
      intValueInRow=0
  Const ForWriting = 2
  Set objFSOOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objOutput = objFSOOut.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting, true)
      for each value in arrAll
        objOutput.Write value
        intValueInRow = intValueInRow + 1  'Argh, there is no "++" operator?
        If (intValueInRow = intValueInRowMax) Then
          objOutput.Write vbNewLine
          intValueInRow=0
        End If
      next
objOutput.Close
Set objFSOOutput = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Nearly) the same idea as Ansgar, different implementation:

```
  Const cnRows = 4    ' to keep the demo simple
  Const cnCols = 3
  Const csFSep = ";"
' Const csRSep = vbLf
  Dim   csRSep : csRSep = vbLf

  Dim aInps : aInps = Array( _
      Join(Array("A1  B1 C1 A2", vbLf, "B2,C2", "comment", vbCrLf, "A3 B3 C3", vbTab, "A4-B4-C4")) _
    , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12" _
    , Join(Array("1.1 -2.2 3.3 4", vbLf, "0.5 -6.6", "comment", vbCrLf, "7 8.0 -9.99", vbTab, "10.10*11.11***-12.12")) _
  )
  ' no need to care for the input format, as long as the valid data can be
  ' specified by a RegExp pattern (and the file contains 'enough' info)
  Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Global  = True
  reCut.Pattern = "([A-Z-])?\d+(\.\d+)?"

  Dim sInp
  For Each sInp In aInps
      WScript.Echo Join(Array("----", vbCrLf, sInp, vbCrLf, "----"), "")
      Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(sInp)
      If oMTS.Count <> cnRows * cnCols Then
         WScript.Echo "Bingo:", oMTS.Count, "<>", (cnRows * cnCols)
      Else
         Dim m
         For m = 0 To oMTS.Count - 1
             WScript.Stdout.Write oMTS(m).Value
             If 0 = (m + 1) Mod cnCols Then WScript.Stdout.Write csRSep Else WScript.Stdout.Write csFSep
         Next
      End If
  Next
```

output:

```
----
A1  B1 C1 A2
 B2,C2 comment
 A3 B3 C3        A4-B4-C4
----
A1;B1;C1
A2;B2;C2
A3;B3;C3
A4;B4;C4
----
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
----
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
10;11;12
----
1.1 -2.2 3.3 4
 0.5 -6.6 comment
 7 8.0 -9.99     10.10*11.11***-12.12
----
1.1;-2.2;3.3
4;0.5;-6.6
7;8.0;-9.99
10.10;11.11;-12.12
```

My pattern tries to identify the valid data and avoids the (maybe costly) string manipulations.

Comment: Concise example. RegExp is flexible for shure. Computation performance is better, the bigger the strAll?

Comment: @StefanBischof You always pay for the additional features of RegExps. That's why you shouldn't use them for operations a string op (like Replace(s, " ", "")) can do just as well. But if not using one RegExp that delivers exactly what you want means to apply many stacked customized/specialized string ops (each scanning a copy of the whole string) then the RegExps is cheaper, even if it takes longer.

Answer (score 1):

For one you seem to have a typo in your procedure `Strg2Array()`.

```
arrAlles(UBound(arrAll)) = ...
```

is probably supposed to be

```
arrAll(UBound(arrAll)) = ...
```

With that said, may I suggest a different approach? Since you seem to have an input file like this:

```
"  -24.1189";"    1.2345";"  124.5290";"   -5.3951";"    2.1062"
"    2.6702";"  -23.1502";"   -1.5028";"   -2.6223";"  -24.3573"
...
```

and seem to want to create semicolon-delimited output with just the numbers (without double quotes and whitespace) like this:

```
-24.1189;1.2345;124.5290;-5.3951;2.1062;...(115 more)...
...
```

I'd use something more like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strAll = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0), 1).ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"

strAll = Replace(strAll, vbNewLine, ";")
strAll = Replace(strAll, """", "")
strAll = re.Replace(strAll, "")

arrAll = Split(strAll, ";")

For i = 0 To UBound(arrAll)
  WScript.StdOut.Write arrAll(i)
  If i Mod 120 = 119 Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine
  Else
    WScript.StdOut.Write ";"
  End If
Next
```

That will read the input from the file given as the first argument to the script, remove double quotes and whitespace, and then write the fields to `StdOut` (120 fields per line). Redirect the output to a new file, and you're finished.

If you need to fill up the last line with empty fields, append something like this:

```
If (i Mod 120) <> 0 Then
  For n = i Mod 120 To 118   ' max. index - 1
    WScript.StdOut.Write ";"
  Next
End If
```

You'd call the script like this:

```
cscript.exe input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: For standard text files (trailing EOL), the "Split" strategy will create an empty/spurious last element in the resulting array.

Comment: You are right, this is a typo. I had to translate my german function names. Thanks for the Modulo operation. Sounds like good old c++ %-Modulo.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Yes, I should've mentioned that. Fixed.